# How to reconnect OpenVPN after sudden disconnected to specific IP port

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have OpenVPN connected to specific application (A) with local port (127.0.0.1:2727). This (A) connected to my main network.

But every time the VPN disconnected, it can't be connected again to (A) because the (A) connected to VPN's ip.

any idea how to resolve this problem ? I want to make the (A) connected to specific network (my main network) after VPN disconnected .
I have tried using ForceBindIP but doesn't work ..

Comment: Are you using something like `redirect-gateway def1` in your OpenVPN config? Then you need a bypass route, because it won’t work properly when OpenVPN connects to `localhost`.

Comment: yes I use redirect-gateway def1 in my config, should I remove it ?

Comment: That depends on what you want. Currently, it’s routing all traffic through the VPN. Is that supposed to happen? Or do you only need to access specific hosts or subnets?

Comment: I just want my application with localhost connect to my main network when VPN reconnecting. I'm using this application as a proxy for my VPN. But every time the VPN reconnecting, it can't be connected again to my application (A) because (A) is using VPN's IP ..

Comment: Yes, you already said that. Again: Do you really want to route all traffic through the VPN?

Comment: yes I do. I need VPN as main connection after connected to my local proxy

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: Add explicit route to mystery program’s remote host (`/32`).

I looked at the [OpenVPN manual](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage), but it remains unclear on whether it can do this natively (via `--route`). To be safe, use scripts/programs with `--up` and `--down`. It’s important to note that modifying the routing config requires root, which you don’t have when `--down` is running if `--user` is also specified.

To be portable, the `--up` script/program would need to do the following, depending on how your mystery program connects:

1. Resolve mystery program remote IP address (`$remote_addr`)
2. Determine gateway (`$gateway`) to remote IP address – this *may or may not* be the default gateway
3. Add explicit route like `ip route add $remote_addr via $gateway`

That way, it’ll work properly with `--redirect-gateway`.

The `--down` script/program would need to perform almost the same, except it has to delete the route.

When writing a (Bash) script, the problems really start as early as step 1. You need only the IP address and nothing else. Something like `getent hosts` would do the trick, but it prefers IPv6 addresses very much, which may or may not be appropriate. Other tools (`dig +short` etc) don’t use the OS resolver but query DNS directly, which may not be what you want (think `/etc/hosts`).

Step two is relatively easy on any OS (`ip route get` etc) but Windows. On Windows, you need to program the algorithm to find the most specific matching route yourself.

**If you feel everything is static** (remote IP address, next hop IP address), you can also use OpenVPN’s `--route`:

```
route 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.255 10.1.2.3
```

...where `1.2.3.4` is the mystery program’s remote host and `10.1.2.3` is the next routing hop to reach it.

---

Another solution is *not* to use `--persist-tun`, meaning the VPN network interface will be completely shut down when OpenVPN loses its connection. That has a very serious implication though: Traffic will leak as soon as the connection is disrupted.